# how to set min-height for bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have problem to set min-height of row from bootstrap. i want my row min-height size as high as the parent element. for example

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 30px;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row header bg-primary">
    <div class="col-6">Title item</div>
    <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
    <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
    <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-100 body bg-success">
    <div class="col-12 h-100">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
        <div class="col-2">item 1</div>
        <div class="col-2">item 1</div>
        <div class="col-2">item 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">item a</div>
        <div class="col-2">item a</div>
        <div class="col-2">item a</div>
        <div class="col-2">item a</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer bg-danger">
    <div class="col-12"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

from example above i want my class body have min-height: 100% fill the entire high of the parent element.

Comment: remove `height:30px` from `.header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex classes - flex-grow-1 tells the content row to expand to fill the available space.

```css
.footer {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row header bg-primary">
        <div class="col-6">Title item</div>
        <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
        <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
        <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-success flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-12 h-100">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row footer bg-danger">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to have your content to just fill the page, then you can have the green area expand to fill the remaining space (`flex-grow-1`) and let the content scroll if the green area is larger than the space.

```css
.footer {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row header bg-primary">
        <div class="col-6">Title item</div>
        <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
        <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
        <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-success flex-grow-1" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="col-12 h-100">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                <div class="col-2">item d</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row footer bg-danger">
        <div class="col-12"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for your reply, the point is how can i make row footer position will be at the bottom of the page. so i try to make row body (green) height stretch until at the bottom of the page so then make the footer wil at the bottom.

Comment: If you just want your content to fill the page (not extend beyond), then you can set the height to `vh-100` and set the green body to `overflow-y: scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

This will make all rows have the equal `height` for the `rows` which has the class `row-equal-height`, if that was what you asked for?

```css
   body {
     height:100%;
   }

   .footer {
      height:100px;
    }
    
.row-equal-height{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
             <div class="container">
          <div class="row row-equal-height   bg-primary">
              <div class="col-6">Title item</div>
              <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
              <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
              <div class="col-2">Title item</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row  row-equal-height  h-100 body bg-success">
              <div class=" col-12 h-100">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">item 1</div>
                    <div class="col-2">item 2</div>
                    <div class="col-2">item 3</div>
                    <div class="col-2">item 4</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">item a</div>
                    <div class="col-2">item b</div>
                    <div class="col-2">item c</div>
                    <div class="col-2">item d</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row footer bg-danger">
            <div class="col-12"></div>
          </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: thx for the reply, my question is how my row body (green) height fill the entire high of the parent (min-height:100%). no matter if there is no item(item 1 or item a) in the content. the row body (green) will fill the entire high of the parent.